# Portfolio-template won't show items

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I have a archive-portfolio.php-file which works fine when visiting the archieve (siteurl.com/portfolio). I then copied the very same code and saved it as a template-file, which I later on selected for a page. The terms/categories are shown correctly, but the portfolio-items doesn't load. Do I miss some arguments for the query? I am using Genesis Framework by the way.

Here is the template-file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Cykler
*/

remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'lp_filterable_portfolio' );

wp_enqueue_script('isotope', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.5.25', true);
wp_enqueue_script('isotope_init', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/isotopes_init.js', array('isotope'), '', true);

function the_excerpt_max_charlength($charlength) {
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $charlength++;
    if ( mb_strlen( $excerpt ) > $charlength ) {
        $subex = mb_substr( $excerpt, 0, $charlength - 5 );
        $exwords = explode( ' ', $subex );
        $excut = - ( mb_strlen( $exwords[ count( $exwords ) - 1 ] ) );
        if ( $excut < 0 ) {
            echo mb_substr( $subex, 0, $excut );
        } else {
            echo $subex;
        }
        echo '[...]';
    } else {
        echo $excerpt;
    }
}

function lp_filterable_portfolio( ){
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'=>-1, 
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    $terms = get_terms( 'portfolio_category' );
    $count=0;
?>

<div class="archive-description">
        <?php if( $terms ) { ?>
            <ul id="portfolio-cats" class="filter clearfix">
                <li><a href="#" class="active" data-filter="*"><span><?php _e('Vis alle', 'lp'); ?></span></a></li>
                <?php
                    foreach( $terms as $term ){
                        echo "<li><a href='#' data-filter='.$term->slug'><span>$term->name</span></a></li>";
                    }
                ?>
            </ul><!-- /portfolio-cats --><br/><br/>
        <?php } ?>

         <?php if( have_posts() ) { ?>
            <div id="portfolio-wrap" class="clearfix filterable-portfolio">
                <div class="portfolio-content">
                    <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
                        <?php $count++; ?>
                        <?php $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_category' ); ?>
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) { ?>
                            <article class="portfolio-item col-<?php echo $count; ?> <?php if( $terms ) foreach ( $terms as $term ) { echo $term->slug .' '; }; ?>">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo genesis_get_image( array( size => 'lp-portfolio' ) ); ?>
                                <div class="portfolio-overlay">
                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                    <p><?php the_excerpt_max_charlength(50);?></p>
                                </div><!-- overlay --></a>
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <p><?php the_excerpt_max_charlength(50);?></p>
                                <a href="#" class="product-readmore">Læs mere</a>
                            </article>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
                </div><!-- /themes-content -->
            </div><!-- /themes-wrap -->
        <?php } ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>

<?php

    wp_reset_postdata();

}

genesis();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's because the "loop" only has one post - the page using the template. You need to query the portfolio posts yourself. And off-topic, this line: `$loop = new WP_Query( $args );` - what's it doing there? It's not used and it's costing you a significant chunk of memory/load time.

Comment: I have tried $loop = new WP_Query( 'post_type=portfolio'); and later while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post(); - but still nothing happens. How can I make the query? @TheDeadMedic